# How do I transfer my Minecraft world from my phone?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I had Minecraft on my Galaxy J3 Prime, and then it got waterlogged. I have a new phone, a Galaxy A20.

I want to know, how can I transfer my Minecraft worlds? I had this one Minecraft map i spent over a week working on, and that would be difficult to remake, so is it possible to use ONLY my A20 to transfer the world file?

Comment: Do you have access to the files on the old phone? This sounds more like an issue of file transfer, if the Minecraft world is only saved on your old device.

Comment: It works yes but it's waterlogged and I don't want to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still are able to access the files on your Galaxy J3 prime, you can go to the following directory using any file explorer:

```
/sdcard0/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds/... (you do not require to have a rooted phone for this)
```

from there you can copy the world and send it to your new phone (send via email, bluetooth, file-sharing websites, etc.), and then copy the world file to your new phone in the same directory.

You mentioned using only your new Galaxy A20 to transfer the world file to your new phone. This is not possible unless you have a cloud backup of the world, since you would still need to have file access to your old phone to get the world.

Comment: I have ES file explorer